# Why can't chrome/chromium connect to website on port 80 (running nodejs app, redirected to port 3000)

Tags: node.js, iptables, port80

I'm having the most peculiar error.

I'm running a web app with nodejs on port 3000, and I set it up to redirect traffic from port 80 to port 3000

The site works fine without specifying the port through Firefox, and on my phone (using chrome), but on my laptop I can't access it through chrome/chromium. Other people are reporting the same issue. When I try to access the site the browser redirects to my ISP's search page.

Comment: Can you send more information on this issue like how you setup redirect traffic and the url?

Comment: I figured it out. On my site's "A" record, i had the "mysite.com" URL registered but not "www.mysite.com". Oy!